# Make background for table rows extend past the bounds of the table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table, css-tables

I'm currently trying to create a table with zebra striping where the background color for the stripes stretches the full length of the screen but the actual contents of the row stay within the bounds of the table.

More specifically, I'm using Bootstrap, so what I'd like is for the contents of the table row act as if they're inside a `.container`.

In essence, I'm trying to create a table which acts like the following:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <div class="container">
            <td>Testing</td>
            <td>Testing</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div class="container">
            <td>Testing</td>
            <td>Testing</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>

...

table, tr {
    width: 100%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f4f4b4;
}
```

Ideally, the background color should extend the full length of the browser window, but the contents of the table should have a centered and fixed (though responsively changing) width.

However, this doesn't actually work since it's [not possible](http://css-tricks.com/using-divs-inside-tables/) to place a `div` inside a `tr` element.

This was my best attempt at solving the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4L4tatk5/3/

It comes close, but doesn't quite work because the cells in the table (outlined in blue) don't align into tidy columns. I tried experimenting with tinkering with different `display` options for `tr` elements, but anything other then `display: block` will cause the `.container` class to effectively be ignored.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

---

The code is available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L4tatk5/3/), but for reference, here's my HTML and CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container control">
    <p>
        This is an example container (outlined in red) to show where the 
        contents of the table should be aligned to. Individual cells are 
        outlined in blue.
    </p>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
        ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
        ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
        lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem 
        ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </p>
</div>
<table class="table test">
    <thead>
        <tr class="container">
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="container">
            <td>abcdefghijklmnop</td>
            <td>123456789</td>
            <td>foo</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="container">
            <td>kidke,fjgisklmpi</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="container">
            <td>abcd</td>
            <td>2321</td>
            <td>hello</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="container">
            <td>adsfaldfalke</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>world</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.control {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.test {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.test thead {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #e2e7e8;
}

.test table {
    width: 100%;
}

.test thead,
.test tbody,
.test tfoot {
    width: 100%;
}

.test tbody:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f4f4b4;
}

.test tr {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.test th,
.test td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: are you aware of the `.table-striped` class in bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables

Comment: @PeterVR - Yes, but adding if I add that class, the background-color doesn't stretch the full length of the screen, only the full length of the table. If I then make the table stretch the entire length of the screen, then the contents of the table aren't aligned as if they're inside a container.

Comment: @PeterVR I don't think his issue is creating the stripes, it's that he wants the stripes to extend past the bounds of the table itself.

Comment: What do you meen by 'aligned as if they're inside a container'?

Comment: @PeterVR - I think Michael summarized what I want to accomplish much more concisely than I did. I've edited my question to try and clarify.

Comment: now I get it, I'll provide a solution...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think `container` class is meant to be used inside tables. I would just place the entire table inside a `.container` and lengthen the stripes using pseudo elements. With the default `table-striped` from bootstrap, that would look something like this:

```
.table-striped td:first-child,
.table-striped th:first-child,
.table-striped td:last-child,
.table-striped th:last-child {
   position: relative;
}

.table-striped td:first-child:before,
.table-striped th:first-child:before,
.table-striped td:last-child:after,
.table-striped th:last-child:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    bottom: -2px;
    width: 100vw;
    display: block;
    background: inherit;
    border: inherit;
}
.table-striped td:first-child:before,
.table-striped th:first-child:before {
    right: 100%;
}
.table-striped td:last-child:after,
.table-striped th:last-child:after {
    left: 100%
}
```

And the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4L4tatk5/8/

Note that you may have to change that `100vw` (= 100% of vertical width) to some other unit (just a ridiculously high `9999px`or something) if you need to support

Comment: I ended up tweaking your code somewhat to fit my particular case better, but the concept of using the before/after pseudo-classes turned out to be exactly what I needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to do but you did it before I got back from work.  Definitely the best solution.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to prevent the overflow-x scrolling on the parent? I don't want to set a max width and can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: @Carson you could add an `overflow: hidden` to the parent of the table (the .container in this case) http://jsfiddle.net/4L4tatk5/40/

Answer (score 1):

The only other way I can see doing this is to use nested tables...

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Item 1</td>
               <td>Item 2</td>
               <td>item 3</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Item 4</td>
               <td>Item 5</td>
               <td>item 6</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

---

I suppose an even simpler solution would be to just use `<div>` containers with a table for each row...

```
<div class="container odd">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Item 1</td>
         <td>Item 2</td>
         <td>item 3</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<div class="container even">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Item 1</td>
         <td>Item 2</td>
         <td>item 3</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

The disadvantages of the above are obvious.  Not dynamic by any means, so if this data is being generated dynamically, this is definitely a no go.  Beyond that it's bloated and not semantic, but you don't have to mess with setting the `<tr>'s` to `display: block;`

In any case I think you can see what you would do with the above, limit the width of the inner tables, and extend the width of the containing elements to 100%, style the containing elements and tada.

---

I have to leave work, but I will take another stab at this when I get home to see if I can't come up with some magic using :before and :after

Comment: You should never change your markup to achieve a certain styling. Markup should be semantic, and the looks should be done purely trough css. I know you basically said this yourself already, but I think this can't be stressed enough!

Comment: @PeterVR - Absolutely, and your method is definitely the better way.  I will note however, that nested tables are technically semantic.  It's not uncommon to need multiple divisions or rows inside a single cell.  Using it in the way I have suggested, would be considered to not be semantic, as it is using the tables element in order to achieve a certain layout and design.  It's not necessary for the data.