# Expand table background-color inside div

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have a table inside a div.
My code: https://jsfiddle.net/2cg29xLc/

HTML

```
<div>
<table>
    <thead>
        <!-- Example with only 2 columns -->
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>this</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bar</td>
            <td>that</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 99%;
}
table {
    border-top: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
thead tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
}
```

My situation:
I want to expand the table's background-color AND border to match the div's width.
To look like this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/2cg29xLc/7/

My headache:
I can't set table's width: 99%

Because the design require columns to have their own width and all the column stay on the left.

I came across this [Make background for table rows extend past the bounds of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273545/make-background-for-table-rows-extend-past-the-bounds-of-the-table)

But I can't get that to work with my code, maybe because I don't use bootstrap.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: define a width for the table in the `table{...}` CSS rule. currently it's unset so defaults to `100%`

Comment: Just apply the css from your 'ideal' fiddle example to your own fiddle.. not sure why that isn't working for you?

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/y6pfowjf/

Comment: why can't you set the table width?

Comment: Google "CSS Flexbox" as a possible alternative (although this *might* require you to set the table width in some dimension)

Comment: @Martin: I already state in the question is that I can't set table's width. Let table has its own width.

Comment: Minh, you are not explaining WHY the table can not have its width set? The column widths are not the same as the table widths, the table width of `%` value does not effect the column width,

Comment: is this homework and you arn't allowed to use `width`?

Comment: @Martin: Ah no, this is a design requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry but that sounds like a really, really poor design requirement. Why not set a width as a `%` value. It doesn't effect absolute values and only gives the widths of the overall table rather than the individual cells

Comment: @Martin: Yup but I will have to set % width for every type of table.
And I have a lot of table with different number of columns
Just looking for different solution :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76274/discussion-between-minh-thin-and-martin).

Comment: It makes me think of someone who wants to drive a car but who is denying themselves the use of 2nd gear.

Comment: why can't every table have a `%` width of `99%` and that applys to all tables being 99% of the size of their container divs? This does not effect cells or table headers individually.

Comment: Yeah but it will look like this https://jsfiddle.net/2cg29xLc/11 , which is ugly and wrong T_T
I need column to have its own width like here https://jsfiddle.net/2cg29xLc/14/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the last column to fill up the remaining space of the table, am I correct? In that case, you can target the last column and apply 100% width to it with the code below :

```
th:last-child{
    width:100%;
    text-align:left;
}
```

And here's the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xundqddc/1/

Comment: Thank you, it works.
Now I feel stupid, so simple :D